# Polylang - display one post into 3 categories with different lang

Tags: posts, categories, plugin-polylang

I use **Plugin Polylang**.
I need to display one post into 3 categories (one category, but for any language the plugin polylang needs to create 3 different categories), it's important to make this without duplicating the post for any category, because I need to make 1 common post(with common rating) for all langs.
I tried in `theme_folder/category.php` before `if ( have_posts() ) :` set:

```
$categories = get_the_category();
        $category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;
        $posts = get_posts( array(
            'category' => pll_get_term($category_id, 'ro'),
            'post_type' => 'post',
        ) );
```

nothing changes...
and:

```
$posts = get_posts( array(
            'category'=> $category_id,
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'lang' => 'ro',
        ) );
```

result: working correctly only if language is 'ro', if I change the language in site, then it displays only empty posts.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to retrieve all posts of all languages in a category, you need to desactivate the auto-translate during the request.
you can try that :

```
$categories = get_the_category();
$category_id = $categories[0]->cat_ID;


remove_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( PLL()->auto_translate, 'get_terms_args' ), 10, 2 );


$posts = [];

foreach (pll_languages_list() as $language_code) {

    $posts = array_merge(
        $posts
        ,
        get_posts([
            "category" => pll_get_term($category_id, $language_code),
            "post_type" => "post",
            "lang" => $language_code,
        ])
    );

}

add_filter( 'get_terms_args', array( PLL()->auto_translate, 'get_terms_args' ), 10, 2 );
```